# Why is PCD bit set when I don't use ioremap_cache?

Tags: dictionary, ram, memory-address, ioremap

I am using ubuntu 12.10 32 bit on an x86 system. I have physical memory(about 32MB,sometimes more) which is enumerated and reserved through the ACPI tables as a device so that linux/OS cannot use it. I have a Linux driver for this memory device. THe driver implements mmap() so that when a process calls mmap(), the driver can map this reserved physical memory to user space. I also sometimes do nothing in the mmap except setup the VMA's and point vma->vmops to the vm_operations_struct with the open close and fault functions implemented. When the application accesses the mmapped memory, I get a page fault and my .fault function is called. Here is use vm_insert_pfn to map the virtual address to any physical address in the 32MB that I want.

Here is the problem I have: In the driver, if I call ioremap_cache() during init, I get good cache performance from the application when I access data in this memory. However, if I don't call ioremap_cache(), I see that any access to these physical pages results in a cache miss and gives horrible performance. I looked into the PTE's and see that the PCD bit for these virtual address->physical translation are set, which means caching on these physical pages is disabled. We tried setting _PAGE_CACHE_WB in the vma_page_prot field and also used remap_pfn_range with the new vma_page_prot but PCD bit was still set in the PTE's.

Does anybody have any idea on how we can ensure caching is enabled for this memory? The reason I don't want to use ioremap_cache() for 32 MB is because there are limited Kernel Virtual Address on 32bit systems and I don't want to hold them.

Comment: Oh! I also want a solution to this because i cannot seem to ioremap_cache() successfully more than 32 MB of physical memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Read [linux/Documentation/x86/pat.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.4/Documentation/x86/pat.txt#L83)
2. Boot Linux with **debugpat**
3. After trying the **set_memory_wb()** APIs, check **/sys/kernel/debug/x86/pat_memtype_list**

Comment: Thanks Scott. I did find this and i tried set_memory_wb() but it doesnt seem to work. I anyway worked around it by calling ioremap_cache() and iounmap() around calls to vm_insert_pfn() etc. I asked around a little more and it looks like these functions call register_memtype() which goes ahead and sets the PCD bit and registers in the PAT list. There is no other exported function, which drivers can call to set the PCD bit as requested. Since this is a 32 bit issue, we worked around it as mentioned above.